Dataframe structure for timeseries sensor readings
Context: there are a verity of different sensors all pushing different parameters depending on their type.  I'm also a noob with data analysis and pandas..
{"sensors": [
 {"ts":1723953456,"temp_screw":{"loc1":95,"lco2":100,"loc3":110,"lco4":145,"loc5":180,"loc6":215}},
 {"ts":1723953458,"temp_head":{"poc1":202,"proc2":208}},
 {"ts":1723953478,"feed_gate":{"main":true,"aux":false}},
 {"ts":1723953482,"temp_nozel":{"temp":225}},
 {"ts":1723953497,"screw_drive":{"speed":56,"load":1458}},
 {"ts":1723953507,"operate":{"state":2,"run_drive":true},"dms":true},
 {"ts":1723953458,"temp_screw":{"loc1":94,"lco2":103,"loc3":111,"lco4":145,"loc5":179,"loc6":213}},
 {"ts":1723953511,"temp_head":{"poc1":204,"proc2":211}}
]}

My question is about structuring the data.  At the moment I can pull all the sensor data in, but I end up with 100+ columns where most of the cells in each row are invalid.
columns:
ts | temp_screw.loc1 | temp_screw.loc2 ... feed_gate.main ...  screw_drive.speed

This feels wrong to me, there's too many empty slots.

Am I one the right path?
Are there better tools for this kind of data.

